# Why does this if statement fail in bourne shell?

Tags: shell, if-statement, sh

I'm learning shell scripting but I can't work out this error, any help much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh
LOCATION=/tmp/loc
PROXY=http://wwwproxy.unimelb.edu.au:8000

http_proxy=$PROXY; export http_proxy
echo "Installing into" $LOCATION

if [ ! -d $LOCATION ]; then mkdir $LOCATION; fi
if [ ! -d $LOCATION/packages ]; then mkdir $LOCATION/packages; fi

TOMCAT_FILE=apache-tomcat-6.0.24.tar.gz
if [ ! -e $LOCATION/packages/$TOMCAT_FILE ]; then
    echo "Downloading" $TOMCAT_FILE
    wget http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.24/bin/apache-tomcat-6.0.24.tar.gz -O $LOCATION/packages/$TOMCAT_FILE
else
    echo "Found" $TOMCAT_FILE
fi
```

It appears to be failing on the third if statement with the error:

```
bash-3.00$ ./install.sh 
Installing into /tmp/loc
./install.sh: test: argument expected
```

(And for those who think they know better how to do this, no I really do have to write a script to take care of this due to external requirements)

Comment: Is this the exact script?  Works for me, after I remove the `http_proxy` assignment, which shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Works for me also (both parts of the final `if/else` execute correctly).

Comment: As an unrelated note, you do not need the first "if", just change the second to `mkdir -p $LOCATION/packages`

Comment: OK, I feel stupid.  I reverted my wrong re-tagging.  Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your `/bin/sh` does not point to the bourne-again shell, as the script works for other people (see comments on your question).

The shebang should be `/bin/bash` for bourne-again shell scripts, but `/bin/sh` will work in some distributions (like Debian) which have a symlink `/bin/sh -> /bin/bash`.

Comment: I was trying to not use bash, but that explains what is going on! (: Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

unless your sh is not aliased to bash, you can try changing the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to write

```
if [ ! -d $LOCATION ]; then mkdir $LOCATION; fi
```

is

```
[ -d $LOCATION ] || mkdir $LOCATION
```